# How can I use linq to remove a certain string from an array while it exists as the first or last element

Tags: c#, linq

If I have array like the following

```
var testArray = new string[] {"??", "??", "FF", "5B", "??", "01", "??" };
```

How can I remove all of the `"??"` elements that appear at the start and end of the array using linq?

For example, in this case I would like to end up with an array like the following

```
{ "FF", "5B", "??", "01" };
```

I understand it is easy enough to remove all occurrences of `"??"` but I would essentially like to only remove `"??"` while they are exist at the start or end of the array.

How could this be done using linq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq alone, you would have to use SkipWhile and Reverse, but this comes at a cost. You would need to reverse the array twice.

```
var r = testArray.SkipWhile(x=>x.Equals("??"))
                 .Reverse()
                 .SkipWhile(x=>x.Equals("??"))
                 .Reverse();
```

Comment: Agreed, LINQ isn't the best solution to this problem. This question likely stems from a homework assignment.

Comment: I see. Is there a more efficient way using for loops then?

Comment: @BrandonMinnick not a homework assignment question. I'm trying to sanitize a user input in the case of them putting "??" at the front or at the back of the input

Comment: It’s most efficient to do this with two if statements than to iterate through the array twice: if(testArray.First().Equals(“??”))  and if(testArray.Last().Equals(“??”))

Answer (score 0):

First, get all the indexes for `"??"` and then loop through the list to remove the first and last element (if any).

```
var testArray = new string[] {"??", "??", "FF", "5B", "??", "01", "??" };
var newList = new List<string>(testArray);

//get all "??" indexes
int[] indexes = testArray.Select((b,i) => b == "??" ? i : -1).Where(i => i != -1).ToArray();

for(int i = indexes.Length - 1; i>=0; i--)
{
    //remove the element only if it's the first or the last one
    if(indexes[i] == 0 || indexes[i] == testArray.Length-1)
    {
        newList.RemoveAt(indexes[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid iterating through the entire array, I recommend converting it to a `List`, then checking the first and last elements.

```
var testArray = new string[] { "??", "??", "FF", "5B", "??", "01", "??" }.ToList();

if (testArray.First().Equals("??"))
    testArray.RemoveAt(0);
if (testArray.Last().Equals("??"))
    testArray.RemoveAt(testArray.Count - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply cleaver and fastest

```
        var testArray = new string[] { "??", "??", "FF", "5B", "??", "01", "??" };
        List<String> list = testArray.ToList();

        //Remove "??" from starting
        for (int i=0;i< list.Count;i++)
        {
            if(list[0]!= "??")
            {
                break;
            }
            list.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        //Remove "??" from ending
        for (int i = list.Count; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (list[list.Count-1] != "??")
            {
                break;
            }
            list.RemoveAt(list.Count-1);
        }
```